# console.log not working inside io.on('connection',....)

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

When I connect to the server the console.log("got a connection") is not shown

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var io = require("http").Server(app);
var socket = require("socket.io")(io);
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
}); 
socket.on("connect", function(socket) {
  //this console.log is not displayed 
  *console.log("got a connection");*
});

io.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server listening to 3000");
});
```

Comment: can it be because it's not connecting?

Comment: could you show us the client code too

Comment: The event is 'connection', not 'connect'.

Comment: nope i used both connnection and connect

Comment: This is the client side code``` <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```